# 1)Как для целого числа N(1 ≤ N ≤ 26 )вывести N первых прописных (то есть больших ) букв латинского алфавита?

Tags: c

и второй вопрос: Как для целого числа N(1 ≤ N ≤ 26 )вывести N последних маленьких букв латинского алфавита в обратном порядке  (начиная с буквы  «z»)?
в функции такс 3 нужно решить первый вопрос 
а в функции таск 4 - второй

```
void task1();
void task2();
void task3();
void task4();
void task5();
void task6();

void main(){
}

void task1(){
   char N;
   do {

      N=getch();
     printf ("\nN: ");
      putchar(N);


        } while (32<=N<=126);
        getch();
}

void task2(){
char C,V;
   char C;
   do {
V=C+1;
      C=getch();

      printf ("You enter %c. ASCII code = %d\n", C, (int)C);
        } while (C<V);
        do {
V=C-1;
      C=getch();

      printf ("You enter %c. ASCII code = %d\n", C, (int)C);
        } while (C>V);

}

void task3(){
char M[100]
printf("\nM:");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    for(int i = 0; i<=n-1; i++)
        scanf("%d",&M[i]);
        for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
            printf("firs 10 elements:%d",M[i]);
        }

}
void task4(){
}
```

Comment: И третий вопрос - вы код пробовали писать?

Comment: да, я пробовал но у меня ничего не получается

Comment: Покажите что пробовали, вам помогут. Пока что это вопрос из серии "Напишите мне код".

Comment: Хорошо, я написал свой код

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Первый:

```
for(int j=0; j < N; ++j)
    printf("%c",'A'+j);
```

Второй:

```
for(int j=0; j < N; ++j)
    printf("%c",'z'-j);
```